# Fetching attribute value from model - Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I wanted to get attributes from model. I tried

```
this.model.get("group_description") and 

this.model.models.get("group_description")
```

But none of them seem to work any help ? Below is snapshot of model structure...[image]

Comment: are you using model or collection?

Comment: You should be using `new View({ collection: ... })` and `this.collection` if your "model" really is a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your object `d` (`this`) is a Backbone.Collection, so you want

```
this.at(0).get("group_description")
```

Comment: perfect! it works modified it to this.model.at .. thanks peter , will accept the answer :)

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Note it seems like you have taken a Backbone.Collection and stored it in a variable called "model", which is probably part of your confusion. Rename that variable to "collection" and you will be less likely to get tripped up.